# Как добавить целую папку в Unversioned Files в Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

В качестве системы контроля версий используется **Subversion**. В окне **Changes** у меня есть три **changelist**'а:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу перенести файлы из папки **Default** в **Unversioned Files**. И я могу перетащить файлы мышкой, но как можно это сделать по-другому? Например, может быть, можно прописать в настройках, какие папки должны находиться в **Unversioned Files**? В **File** -> **Settings** -> **Version Control** -> **Ignored Files** 4 папки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в **Unversioned Files** только одна папка, **production**. Это тоже немного непонятно... Т.е., **Ignored Files** и **Unversioned Files** никак между собой не связаны?

Comment: Для чего вы хотите перенести файлы? Ignore files - изменения этих файлов игнорируются свн, unversioned files - файлы которых нет в свн,

Comment: @a.chugunov, я хотела добавить её для игнорирования svn

Comment: тогда вам нужно добавить папку в IgnoredFiles по аналогии с существующими.